# Configuring Promiscuous Mode in VMware Workstation running on Windows 10 serving two Linux guests

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I'm having difficulties configuring [Promiscuous Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) in VMware Workstation 12 hosted on Windows 10 serving two Linux guests.

For instance, this is what I'm trying to configure in VMware Workstation: 
[image]

- VM 1 – transmitting recorded traffic on a designated private network
- VM 2 – receiving the incoming traffic from VM 1, connected to the same private network

Assuming both Linux guests are configured properly for Promiscuous Mode, how should I configure the network in VMware Workstation to support that?

---

While it's pretty straight-forward to configure Promiscuous Mode on ESXi, I couldn't find the matching setting in VMware Workstation.

[image]
- ESXi screenshot for instance

Answer (score 1):

Shut down the VMware host. Locate the VMX file associated with it. Edit the file and locate the Ethernet section. Add a new entry for each Ethernet you want to be in promiscuous mode:

```
  ethernet%d.noPromisc = "FALSE"
```

(replace `%d` with the Ethernet number)

Start the machine and the interface will now operate in promiscuous mode.

[source](https://s3.amazonaws.com/virtuallyghetto-download/hidden_vmx_params.html) — which cautions that its advice should be used at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for the information, so far the default settings got us promiscuous behavior working on some systems and didn't on other systems (unstable). I'll definitely going to recommend our support technicians to try this on their next attempt.